# Outliers not showing up in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, iplots

Hi I am using this code to generate a boxplot:
[image]

However, it is not showing all the data points also not showing up the outliers on the top. I am using this code:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(dataset, y= 'Report_used',hover_name='entity_name')
fig.show()
```

It needs to be like this:

[image]

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Usually outliers have values significantly smaller than min and greater than max values, but in the desired plot, the outliers are within the min and max?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box(dataset,
    y= 'Report_used',
    hover_name='entity_name',
    points='all')
fig.update_traces(pointpos=0)
fig.show()
```

If you wanted all the points to be on the whisker line:

```
fig.update_traces(pointpos=0, jitter=0)
```